# On nixos - successfully building a package with nix-build, but unable to import it into my configuration.nix

Tags: nix, nixos

On nixos. My goal is to run a deno script in a regular interval.

To do so, I have a derivation for the script on my my machine, and I want to use it in my `configuration.nix`, and include it in a systemd service.

#### The Working Derivation:

```hs
# path/to/my-package/default.nix

{ pkgs ? import <nixpkgs> {} }:

with pkgs;

let
  source = stdenv.mkDerivation {
    name = "main-file";
    src = builtins.path { name = "main-file-dir"; path = ./.; };
    installPhase = ''
      mkdir -p $out
      cp main.ts $out/
    '';
  };
in
let
  myScript = pkgs.writeShellScriptBin "myscript" ''
    ${pkgs.deno}/bin/deno run ${source}/main.ts
  '';
in
stdenv.mkDerivation rec {
  name = "my-package";

  src = builtins.path { name = "my-package-src"; path = ./.; };

  buildInputs = [ source myScript pkgs.deno ];

  # this is kinda not doing anything, but it fails without it
  installPhase = ''
    mkdir -p $out/bin
  '';
}
```

Running `nix-build` succeeds without a problem.
Running `nix-shell default.nix` pops me into a shell, and I can happily run `myscript` and the script runs.
This is all well and good!

#### The problem

However, when I go to import it. and run `sudo nixos-rebuild switch`. It throws an error! Here's what that looks like:

```hs
# configuration.nix

{ config, pkgs, ... }:

let
  myPackage = import path/to/my-package/default.nix { inherit pkgs; };
in
 ...
 services.systemd.my-service = {
  ... #use `myPackage` here.
 }
 ...
```

**And the error thrown is:**
`attribute 'deno' missing, at path/to/my-package/default.nix:17:7`

### The question:

- What could be going wrong here? It seems like the attribute set in pkgs is different when running `nixos-rebuild switch` then when running `nix-build`.
- How can I even see if those are indeed different attribute sets? What might I do to debug things?

Any ideas?

#### Some paths I've walked

I've tried a number of different ways of importing it - all which lead to basically the same result:

`import path/to/my-package/default.nix { inherit pkgs; };`
`callPackage path/to/my-package/default.nix { };`

Comment: Maybe you have a different channel configuration for root and for your user? Could you try `nix-instantiate '<nixpkgs>' --eval --expr` and `sudo nix-instantiate '<nixpkgs>' --eval --expr`?

Comment: Aha! Indeed I do! The root version pointed to `/nix/var/nix/profiles/per-user/root/channels/nixos` and the user version pointed to: 
`/home/strickinato/.nix-defexpr/channels/nixpkgs`. 

QUESTION: Is this a desirable state? If not, anything you could point me to to rectify it? If so, any tips for updating the root channel? (`sudo nix-channel --update` didn't seem to get me there)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have a different channel configuration for root and for your user, as can be seen from the difference between

```bash
nix-instantiate '<nixpkgs>' --eval --expr
```

and

```bash
sudo nix-instantiate '<nixpkgs>' --eval --expr?
```

I've stopped using channels and I'll switch from my custom solution to flakes soon. If you want to keep using channels, you could configure either user's `NIX_PATH` to point to the other channel, and always use that user to update the channel.

I can't reproduce your situation in a test VM, which reads:

```bash
[alice@machine:~]$ echo $NIX_PATH
nixpkgs=/nix/var/nix/profiles/per-user/root/channels/nixos:nixos-config=/etc/nixos/configuration.nix:/nix/var/nix/profiles/per-user/root/channels
```

I wish I had a more specific recommendation for `nix-channel`, but the truth of the matter is that the community is moving away from it.
Before flakes, some people used their own custom setup. With flakes, a setup without `nix-channel` or even `NIX_PATH` is within reach.

Beware of the "nix registry" though. It is a lot like channels, but unlike channels, you can actually avoid it easily.